# How does this work? I multiply a matrix with some power and i get back a number?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the matrix \begin{bmatrix}6&0&0\\0&6&0\\0&0&6\end{bmatrix}

If i raise that to the $10th$ power, textbook says that i will get $(6^3)^{10}$

How does this happen? How do i get a number instead of a matrix?

Comment: Label the matrix $M.$ I think the book means that the *determinant* of $M$ is $6^3$, and so the determinant of $M^{10}$ is $(6^3)^{10}.$

Answer (score 5):

You don't. That number is the *determinant* of the $10$<sup>th</sup> power of the matrix. But the $10$<sup>th</sup> power of the matrix is the matrix $6^{10}\operatorname{Id}_3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}6&0&0\\0&6&0\\0&0&6\end{bmatrix} = 6 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} = 6\mathbf{I}$$

$$\mathbf{I}^2 = \mathbf{I} \implies \mathbf{I}^n=\mathbf{I} ~~(\forall n \in \mathbf N)$$
So eventually when you take the n-th power of $A$, you will get
$$A^n = 6^n \mathbf{I}^n = 6^n \mathbf{I} = \begin{bmatrix}6^n&0&0\\0&6^n&0\\0&0&6^n\end{bmatrix}$$

Now I presume what your textbook is stating that the determinant of the matrix $A^{10}$ is $6^{30}$. The determinant in this case is simply the product of the diagonal elements of $A^{10}$, therefore
$$\det (A^{10}) = 6^{10} * 6^{10} * 6^{10} = 6^{30}$$